# JACKSON Mapping XML config Without Annotations

Tags: mapping, jackson

I have a library of objects, whose source code is not editable so cant annotate them, is there another way to config Jackson Mapper like via XML.

Comment: It'd be good to elaborate on kinds of things you need annotations for, just to make sure answers can address specific needs.

Comment: I haven't found a way so far, but I would love the feature if it existed: I see no reason why objects created by Jackson should know anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you want to configure? Often there isn't need to configure anything.

One way to use annotations without modifying value classes is to use "mix-in annotations" (see, for example [this](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html))

Comment: Is it possible with Spring config to introduce these mixins as i dont want any build time dependencies in domain model

Comment: I have no idea, I don't use Spring, so perhaps ask it on Spring mailing list. Still I am curious as to what kind of things you want to configure? If you want to enable features, spring config can be used to enable features of ObjectMapper.

Comment: I want to be able to tell configure ignore annotations in one environment but include in another for example i want some properties included in web services but when requested from webpage i want to ignore some relations, Because i dont want to rebuild and redpoly for evey enviornment just want in externalize this configuration may in XML as i am doing with most other technologies i am useing like JPA, Validation, and others

Comment: Ok. So no, there is no functionality for external definitions -- sounds like potential extension module someone might want to write, as doing so is possible. But so far no one has needed it badly enough I guess. :)